# How to convert .NET WPF application to Windows Forms?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

We have created a beautifully designed .NET WPF desktop application. We are installing the application with InnoSetup , and if .NET 3.5 is not present, it automatically installs it. However, the package to download .NET 3.5 is huge and we found out that about 30% of users do not finish instalation due to this.

The obvious solution is to recode everything into .NET 1.1 with Windows Forms but its a major development which would take few weeks. Also, we would then face dilemma if to support both versions (and use innosetup to choose the right one) or just ditch WPF all together.

Is there any easy way how to convert WPF to Windows Forms? Or do we have any alternative options to consider?

Thank you!

Comment: I assume you mean .NET 2.0 instead of .NET 1.1? Did you already have a look at the .NET 3.5 client profile? It includes a reduced set of assemblies which are typically needed for client (WPF-)applications: http://blogs.windowsclient.net/trickster92/archive/2008/05/21/introducing-the-net-framework-client-profile.aspx

Comment: @divo: Janusz probably *does* mean .NET 1.1, since it's (slightly) more ubiquitous than 2.0, which still has a 23 MB installer.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: I don't think so. It's been a long time I have seen a machine without .NET 2.0 installed. .NET 2.0 comes with WinXP SP3, Vista and Win7 (where 3.5 SP1 is included), whereas .NET 1.1 never has been included in any Windows version.

Comment: @divo: the .NET Framework 1.1 was included in Windows Server 2003

Comment: @Enrico Campidoglio: He says that this is a desktop application, not a server application.

Comment: @divo: you're right: http://www.msigeek.com/2390/what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-which-version-of-the-os

Comment: Janusz needs to target .NET 1.0 instead of 1.1, or he'll miss out on the 4 customers who are stuck on 1.0.

Comment: Or to put it simply, don't use .NET at all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Converting WPF to WinForms is not trivial, there is certainly no automated way, and if you want to go back to .net 1.1 as well you'll lose a whole load of other features like generics etc, so it's not just the UI you'll be changing.

The best solution would be to target the [.net client profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx) instead. It's a much smaller download.

If you can wait a few weeks, the client profile in .net 4.0 has far better offline installation and platform support. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/jgoldb/archive/2009/10/19/what-s-new-in-net-framework-4-client-profile-beta-2.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912%28VS.100%29.aspx#differences_between_net_framework_client_profile_versions).

Comment: 3.5 is ~28mb (but it's a web install only - read the links for how this works, it can end up falling back to a full install), 4.0 is a proper redistributeable download and is 30-50mb depending on the platform.

Comment: Thanks to all for all your thoughts. Its very helpful. I wasn't aware of .net client profile and this may be something which could improve the download-to-install conversion without pain of redoing app for .NET 1.1/2

I will experiment with .net client profile and will check new version as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [.NET Client Profile](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-client-profile.aspx) introduced in .NET 3.5 SP1 in order to reduce the size of the download required to run the app on computers without the .NET Framework 3.5 installed.

The .NET Client Profile is about 28 MB in size, as described [here](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-intro-client-profile.aspx).

Also, have a look at [this site](http://www.hanselman.com/smallestdotnet/) to determine the smallest, easiest download required to get the .NET Framework on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say "beautifully designed", I'm going to assume that you made extensive use of WPF's UI elements.  If this is the case, forget about porting the UI back to WinForms.

The non-UI parts of your program can be back-ported easily (possibly with no changes at all) IFF (if and only if) they don't reference any post-2.0 stuff (like LINQ, for example).

Comment: Even if they use LINQ, they can be backported easily by using the C# 3.0 compiler to target the 2.0 framework and ship a LINQ implementation (e.g. Mono's) with the application.

But yes, all UI code will have to be rewritten for the WinForms port.

Comment: If the sun weren't shining, I might contest your use of the word "easily" here. :)

Comment: I actually just had to move an app (not WPF) back from 3.5 to 2.0. It was easier to just strip out the LINQ entirely, as the developer who pushed for its inclusion only used it in place of `for` loops.

Comment: Its just mainly WPF including animations. I think it would be very difficult to do them without WPF but possibly the benefit of high download-to-install conversion could outweight the benefits of having the application with animations.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [Client only framework subset](https://web.archive.org/web/20160711172319/http://demiliani.com/blog/archive/2008/05/15/6485.aspx)?  You just check a box in your project setup and it will use a slimmed down 26 mb version of .net 3.5.  It is also known as Client Profile
[image]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/pietrobr/WindowsLiveWriter/.NETFramework3.5ClientProfile_8AF0/clip_image002_thumb.gif))</sub>